# how to Change boolean value with hidden form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, boolean

Im trying to set up a button that will flag a post as inappropriate.

All posts are set to have an initial value of 'false' for a :flag value. Ive set up a hidden form for the button that will set the :flag boolean value to true when clicked in the show page for the post. When I submit the button I get a blank page that says not allowed. Any help would be appreciated!

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_account!, except: [:show, :index]
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  
def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    if @post.account != current_account
      return render plain: 'Not Allowed', status: :forbidden
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def post_params
   params.fetch(:post, {}).permit(:title,:contact , :content, :category_id, :genre_id, :city_id, :instrument_id, :flag)
end
```

Hidden form in show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post, {:url => post_path(@post), :method=>:patch} do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :flag, value: true %>
  <%= f.submit 'flag', class: 'btn btn-warning' %>
<% end %>
```

migration AddFlagToPost

```
class AddFlagToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :posts, :flag, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't even have an `#update` method in the provided controller.

Comment: It is included in my project. I am new at rails and wasnt sure if that information was needed to figure out the solution. I just added it in my post. Thank you!

Comment: There is still a bunch of holes in this question. What are the exact steps you did when sending the request? What does the rails log tell you about the error? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: it seems i had some typos in the description. it has been fixed. How do you get the log for the error? as i have stated, i only get a white page that says "not allowed.".

Comment: It seems like the error could be returned because of account check, maybe you should investigate if current_account value is not correct?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the except show. like this: `before_action :authenticate_account!, except: [:index]`

Comment: I see! so flagging should be an available function for everyone (current_user or not). with my update controller as it is, will I need to fix the update method to allow flagging to be done by any user?

Comment: You can see the logs either by looking at the terminal window where you are running the rails server or the files in the `/logs` directory. For example `tail -f logs/development.log`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: also, coming from my log after hitting the flag button i get this line where it looks like its trying to change the correct value(flag) to true. Still getting the 'not allowed' blank white page after removing `:show` from the  `before_action :authenticate_account!, except: [:show, :index]`

log : `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"972qv1fIVw88cLcYZcFpdS1Mt74PvPcrSuUGjoFkLxGfzyjwVeN33mBvgkt11l/+9eGGwePGSz1oJY9SxO0gow==", "post"=>{"flag"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"flag", "id"=>"1"}`